# What's the best way to add scripting to an Android app?

Tags: android, scripting

I have an XML based file format that I'm using to store and load instances of objects.  I'm interested in adding some scripting support to those objects so that they can respond to events.

That said, I also don't want to cripple performance.  Are there any well known scripting options for Android - maybe even ones where while loading, I can pre-compile and cache the scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present it looks as though there are limited options to have a scripting language pre-compile.

Another approach I might look into is seeing if I can use dynamically loaded classes.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting

Comment: I noticed that this is a scripting host, but does it have a smaller footprint library-edition that can be integrated with applications?

Comment: If you need a really small footprint and good performance, just embed Lua yourself.

Comment: Is that relatively easy to do in an android app?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but take a look at this : http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/lua-on-android.html, but the page actually points back to the android-scripting page on code.google.

Comment: I'm not too sure if I'm up for that much wrestling, I was hoping for a library/package I could make use of.